# how to fbx sdk export binary fbx file with python

Tags: autodesk

i want to export binary fbx file with python throw autodesk fbx sdk,but the export file has not Material, and export ascii fbx, it can work well .could someone help me?
ps:
how to use fbx convert export ascii fbx file to binary file in linux,i search the convert in autodesk website ,is does not support the Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want material to be exported, you need to add

```
pSdkManager.GetIOSettings().SetBoolProp(EXP_FBX_MATERIAL, True)
pSdkManager.GetIOSettings().SetBoolProp(EXP_FBX_TEXTURE, True)
pSdkManager.GetIOSettings().SetBoolProp(EXP_FBX_EMBEDDED, True) # or False if you want ASCII
```

To choose between binary and ascii

```
pFileFormat =pSdkManager.GetIOPluginRegistry().GetNativeWriterFormat()
if not pEmbedMedia:
    lFormatCount =pSdkManager.GetIOPluginRegistry().GetWriterFormatCount()
    for lFormatIndex in range(lFormatCount):
        if pSdkManager.GetIOPluginRegistry().WriterIsFBX(lFormatIndex):
            lDesc =pSdkManager.GetIOPluginRegistry().GetWriterFormatDescription(lFormatIndex)
            if "ascii" in lDesc:
                pFileFormat =lFormatIndex
                break
```

and use pFileFormat in the Exporter.Initialize() call.

The FbxConverter was never released for Linux, so no option there. Whoever since you got the Python binding, and since the SDK can do the same thing as the application, why not doing a simple Python command line converter?

Comment: @jing-ya, did it help?